# On resize isn't working with my height calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

So I am using a fixed sidebar which when it reaches a certain point swaps to absolute in order to stop it from scrolling and leaves it at the bottom of the div. Once you scroll back up it swaps back to fixed and scrolls with the page.

I want to make the size of sidebar update to match the size of the column on resize, currently you have to refresh the page in order to make it pick up the new column size.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('main-column').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('main-sidebar').style.height = offsetHeight+'px';

$(window).resize(function() {
    var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('main-column').offsetHeight;
    clearTimeout(this.id);
});

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 150 + $('#main-sidebar').offset().top + offsetHeight - window.innerHeight) {
        $('.sidebar-wrap').addClass('scroll');
    } else {
        $('.sidebar-wrap').removeClass('scroll');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="main-page">
    <div class="row-2col-left">
        <div class="column" id="main-column">
            <?php
                if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
                    yoast_breadcrumb('
                    <p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>
                    ');
                }
            ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) :
               while (have_posts()) :
                  the_post();
                     the_content();
               endwhile;
            endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar" id="main-sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-wrap" id="sidebar-wrap">
                <?php get_sidebar('sidebar-1'); ?>
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Sidebar Styles */
.wrap .main-page .row-2col-left .sidebar {
position: relative; }

.wrap .main-page .row-2col-left .sidebar .sidebar-wrap {
position: fixed; }

.wrap .main-page .row-2col-left .sidebar .sidebar-wrap.scroll {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0; }
```

**EDIT: For anyone interested in this, I completed the function which resizes the sidebar both on load and then on resize as well as updating the positioning of how far the sidebar needs to scroll both on load and resize.**

[Fixed Sidebar with Relative height and Fluid Absolute Transitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075347/fixed-sidebar-with-relative-height-and-fluid-absolute-transitioning)

Comment: well there is no `').Height;` and you do nothing with `offsetHeight` afterwards, it is not going to update `'main-sidebar`

Comment: It does currently update the size of the main-sidebar however it does not on resize.

Comment: because the issues I stated, there is no .Height and updating the variable does not magically update the line that already ran. That code is done, updating the variable does not change the reference.

Comment: Then please suggest an edit, the height was a previous typo and has been amended, when I pass the same line of code previously fired to allow it to set the height under the resize function it does not work and therefore has not been included in the question.

Comment: you set the height....

Comment: the height is the exact same height of the column. It picks up a height perfectly fine it just does not on resize.

Comment: As I stated multple times `document.getElementById('main-sidebar').style.height = offsetHeight+'px';` does not update automatically..... You need to call it again.

Comment: Does the `doneResizing()` function (which you have not shown here) try to  set the sidebar height? Or do you only have that on document load?

Comment: The doneResizing() was my tracker to ensure that the resize function was firing and not firing until the resize was complete, removed it from code.

Comment: I think you want to keep it (and have it actually do the height setting, which was the goal in the first place, right?)

Comment: Daniel Beck, it served no other purpose than echoing out a link once the resize had fired to show it worked. The height is calculated from the 2nd and 3rd line in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a variable does not change the code that already used that variable. You need to run the code again to set the new height.

```
function updateHeight() {
  var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('main-column').offsetHeight;
  document.getElementById('main-sidebar').style.height = offsetHeight+'px';
}

$(window).resize(updateHeight).trigger('resize')

// If you need the timeout logic
// updateHeight()
// $(window).resize(function() {
//     updateHeight()
//     clearTimeout(this.id);
//     this.id = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
// });
```

Comment: @espascarello Did he update the variable or did he re-declare the variable?

Comment: @DanielBeck why? Figured `doneResizing` calls some other logic.... since OP did not share it.