# Fixed Sidebar with Relative height and Fluid Absolute Transitioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, sass

I am looking to achieve a fixed sidebar that will scroll to the bottom of the div and then will change into an absolutely positioned element in order to stop it continuing down the page.

When you scroll back up the sidebar returns to position fixed. The sidebar needs to inherit the same height as the column next to it in order for the fixed sidebar to not look strange. The size of the sidebar needs to alter when the screen is resized in order to match the column.

So far I have been able to:

- Make the code that inherits the height of the column and applies it to the div.
- Make the code that recalculated the height on window resize.
- Make the code that changes the positioning from fixed -> absolute and vise versa

I have made the code the calculates how far the div should scroll however this is where I run into issues:

- I need it to update the distance it scrolls relative to the sidebar on window resize (I think it means just running the script again inside the resize im not too sure)
- The calculation of how far it should scroll is relative to the height of the users browser and therefore does not scroll to the correct point when on a 15" screen compared to a 23"

I am looking for some help on making the script that calculates the distance it should scroll fire on resize as well in order to create a seamless experience.

As well as some help on figuring out the correct equation to use so it appears correctly in all instances of the browser window.

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('main-column').offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById('main-sidebar').style.height = offsetHeight+'px';

    function updateHeight() {
      var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('main-column').offsetHeight;
      document.getElementById('main-sidebar').style.height = offsetHeight+'px';
    }

    $(window).resize(updateHeight).trigger('resize')

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 40 + $('#main-sidebar').offset().top + offsetHeight - window.innerHeight) {
            $('.sidebar-wrap').addClass('scroll');
        } else {
            $('.sidebar-wrap').removeClass('scroll');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="main-page">
    <div class="row-2col-left">
        <div class="column" id="main-column">
            <?php
                if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
                    yoast_breadcrumb('
                    <p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>
                    ');
                }
            ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) :
               while (have_posts()) :
                  the_post();
                     the_content();
               endwhile;
            endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar" id="main-sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-wrap" id="sidebar-wrap">
                <?php get_sidebar('sidebar-1'); ?>
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS/CSS

```
.wrap {

    .main-page {


        .row-2col-left {

            .sidebar {
                position: relative;
                width: 30%;

                .sidebar-wrap {
                    position: fixed;
                }

                .sidebar-wrap.scroll {
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0;
                }
            }

            .column {
                width: 70%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I amended this by editing the code used for calculating the scroll distance:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= offsetHeight - 100) {
        $('.sidebar-wrap').addClass('scroll');
    } else {
        $('.sidebar-wrap').removeClass('scroll');
    }
});
```

Because we already know the offsetHeight is equal to that of the sidebar height, I then messed around with subtracting values until it was fluent. If you was to use this code I believe you would have to change the value of **- 100** in order to make it work.

**EDIT: I made it all into 1 function and enabled everything to update on window resize which also only fires once the resize is complete.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    function updateScroll() {

        var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('main-column').offsetHeight;
        document.getElementById('main-sidebar').style.height = offsetHeight+'px';

        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() >= offsetHeight - 100) {
                $('.sidebar-wrap').addClass('scroll');
            } else {
                $('.sidebar-wrap').removeClass('scroll');
            }
        });
    }

        $(window).resize(updateScroll).trigger('resize')
    });
</script>
```